# Facebook PHP SDK 3.0.1 photo tagging not working. getting (121) Invalid photo id error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tagging

can anyone help me with photo tagging using facebook's PHP SDK? I have tried a lot but its not working for me. i was using php sdk 2.1 and i was perfectly working. now it is also showing error "(#121) Invalid photo Id"

Comment: I have the same problem Please vote for this Bug here to solve it sooner http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18084

Answer (score 3):

Solution

add this permission to the required permissions:
user_photos